# Ubuntu upgrade failed, now I can't boot with "Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"

Tags: ubuntu, grub

As the title states, I can't boot and I get VFS error".  Below is a bunch of info.  Hopefully you can help me boot again.
Thanks

```
#grub.lst
title           Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS, kernel 2.6.32-24-generic<BR>
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic root=UUID=a2ee2642-6929-4932-9eeb-53e483022f6f ro quiet splash
quiet

#fstab
UUID=a2ee2642-6929-4932-9eeb-53e483022f6f /               ext3    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0       1

 #contents of /boot
abi-2.6.32-24-generic
config-2.6.32-24-generic
grub
initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic
memtest86+.bin
System.map-2.6.32-24-generic
vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-24-generic
vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by installing grub2.  Not sure exactly what was wrong.